# How to color the cells of a table based on values

Tags: r

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(INT = c("BOI_CHA", "BPD_SLE", "BPG_SLE", "BPG_BPD", 
"SLE_GVC", "SLE_ANN", "BPG_CHA", "SLE_CHA", "BPG_ANN", "BPG_GVC", 
"BPG_SLE_ABL", "SLE_BOI", "BOI_ANN", "CHA_ANN", "BPG_BOI", "SLE_BOI_ABL", 
"BPG_BPD_SLE", "BPD_ANN", "BPG_BOI_ABL", "BPD_SLE_ABL", "BPD_GVC", 
"CHA_GVC", "BPD_CHA", "BPG_BPD_ABL", "ANN_GVC"), E66 = c(2L, 
35L, 161L, 12L, 21L, 27L, 22L, 8L, 35L, 157L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), K449 = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T8550 = c(20L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), T8558 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    T856 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K219 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K316 = c(0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K318 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K910 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Z422 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), K310 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Z090 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K20 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Z4588 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My goal is to find an R package that allows me to color each cell according to its values `(cf figure below)`.The color should be darker when the value is higher and lighter when the value is lower. I have a preference for Brown-orange_yellow (from darker to lighter).

[image]

Comment: hi Seydou! When you say cells, what are you referring to? In Excel or gt or something else?

Comment: @Mark I edited my  code by providing more information

Answer (score 0):

You can color the cells of a table using the `kableExtra` package. *Also, in the future, be sure to use a minimum representative example - we do not need all of your rows and columns to answer your question.*

```
# load packages you will need
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

# Example data
dat <- data.frame(
  INT = c("BOI_CHA", "BPD_SLE", "BPG_SLE"),
  E66 = c(2, 35, 161),
  K449 = c(1, 10, 20)
)

# Create table
dat %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic() %>%
  column_spec(2, color = 'black', background = c("#fed98e","#d95f0e","#993404")) %>% 
  column_spec(3, color = 'black', background = c("#993404","#d95f0e","#fed98e"))
```

[image]

- Here is a helpful resource for changing different aspects of a table made using `kableExtra` - [link here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)
- Additionally, this is a helpful resource for getting hex color codes -
  [link here](https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=YlOrBr&n=5)